# python character set conversion by the compiler

Tags: python, utf-8, character

```
C:\c>python -m pydoc wordspyth^A.split
```

> no python documentation found for 'wordspyth\x01.split'

I understand that python documentation doesn't exist, but why does `^A` convert to `\x01`?

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> is a control character with value 1, those are  echoed hexidecimal by default. As they might break your prompt/terminal and/or would be illegible.

That pydoc doesn't know about the non-standard function `wordspyth` doesn't mean there is no [documentation](https://www.python.org/doc/)

Answer (score 0):

Like Anthon said , `ctrl + A` is a non-printable character , when you add that to a string in python and the string is printed out, python internally converts many such non-printable characters to printable unicode format.

This was done in Python 3000 through  http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3138/